# Grabbing a part of the List<Item> by start and end indices

Tags: c#, list

Is this possible?

For example, if I have

```
List<Item> myList = new List<Item>;

//added 100 of Items to myList

//then I want to grab items at indices 50 - 60

List<Item> myNewList = myList.?
```

How do I do that without looping through myList?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a method that retrieves these items, List.GetRange.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx

```
List<Item> myList = new List<Item>;
myList.GetRange(50, 10); // Retrieves 10 items starting with index #50
```

Comment: probably OP wants 11 items ;)

Comment: Pity this is not available for `IList` and `IReadOnlyList`.

Answer (score 9):

```
var myNewList  = myList.Skip(50).Take(10);
```

Comment: Reading through the documentation for "skip" and "take", it appears that they use the underlying IEnumerable logic.  Does this mean the performance is O(number of items skipped)?  i.e. is skipping 100 slower than skipping 50?

Comment: @TedSpence yes it has to be. Not sure if there are specific optimizations performed, like checking whether underlying IEnumerable is IList and so on. Doesn't look like so from these links which say List<T>.GetRange will be more efficient for larger collections: https://icodeit.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects/, http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx

Comment: Using this rather than `GetRange()` means it also works regardless of whether it's an Array or List.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx

```
myList.Skip(50).Take(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        //added 100 of Items to myList
        for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        {
            myList.Add("blablabla");
        }

        //then I want to grab items at indices 50 - 60
        // Note: 50 - 60 inclusivly are actually 11 items
        List<string> myNewList = myList.GetRange(50, 11);
```