# How to get items in a specific range (3 - 7) from list?

Tags: c#, list

What would be the most efficient way to select all the items in a specific range from a list and put it in a new one?

```
List<DataClass> xmlList = new List<DataClass>();
```

This is my List, and I would like to put all the DataClass items between the range (3 - 7) in a new List.

What would be the most efficient way? A foreach loop that that count++ everytime untill he reaches the items between a the range and add those items to the new list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing a part of the List<Item> by start and end indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566857/grabbing-a-part-of-the-listitem-by-start-and-end-indices)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The method you are seeking is [GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<int> i = new List<int>();
List<int> sublist = i.GetRange(3, 4);

var filesToDelete = files.ToList().GetRange(2, files.Length - 2);
```

From the summary:

```
// Summary:
//     Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.
// Parameters:
//   index:
//     The zero-based System.Collections.Generic.List<T> index at which the range
//     starts.
//   count:
//     The number of elements in the range.
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd line be `...GetRange(3, 5);` so that it gets indices 3, 4, 5, 6, 7?

Answer (score 51):

In case the source collection is not a `List<T>`, but some other collection that implements `IList<T>` or just `IEnumerable<T>` you can write the following statement using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<int> list = ...
var sublist = list.Skip(2).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the `ToList` extension instead: `List<int> copy = list.Skip(2).Take(5).ToList()`. It is basically doing the same thing but I find it a more natural fit for a LINQ expression.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Note that that it's merely a visual difference, unless you're dealing with an anonymous type (in which case you *need* `ToList`).  Functionally the two are virtually identical.

Comment: Note that List<T>.GetRange will be more efficient though for larger collections: https://icodeit.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects/, http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx

Comment: `GetRange()` can throw `ArgumentException (Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection)`, while `Skip().Take()` won't.

Comment: For my use-case when I need to cut a list from 2 million records - the `GetRange` approach takes just about 60ms, while the `Skip().Take()` is taking more than 6000 ms. I would suggest using `GetRange` whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

List implements a `CopyTo` method that lets you specify the start and number of elements to copy. I'd suggest using that.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eb2b9x8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

in c# 8 you can use Range and Index instead of Linq take and skip for List

****notice**: before using you should convert the list to array**

> Sample array:

```
string[] CountryList = { "USA", "France", "Japan", "Korea", "Germany", "China", "Armenia"};  
var countryArray = CountryList.ToArray();
```

> To get this result (element 1,2,3) ==> France Japan Korea

> 1: Get a range of array or list:

```
   var newArr = countryArray[1..3]
```

> 2: Define Range object

```
Range range = 1..3;  
    var newArr = countryArray[range])
```

> 3: Use Index Object

```
Index startIndex = 1;  
Index endIndex = 3;  
var newArr = countryArray[startIndex..endIndex]
```

Comment: `List<T>` does not support the new range syntax.

Comment: @Chronicle yes, you can use  List.ToArray()[range ]